# UserType field in the APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I updated wso2 from version 2.6.0 to 4.1.0 and in the old version, only this JWTGenerator generator class which was received as a *TokenValidationContext* as a parameter *'context'* and from this *context.getUserType()* was obtained, which is still needed.

**How to get userType field in APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl if it accepts JWTInfoDto class as a parameter?**

And why is it hardcoded in the APIMgtGatewayJWTGeneratorImpl class as *claims.put(dialect + "usertype", "Application_User")*?

I serialized JWTInfoDto in JSON and output it to the logs, I got the following:

```
{
  "applicationTier": "Unlimited",
  "keyType": "PRODUCTION",
  "version": "v1",
  "applicationName": "Yaroslav",
  "endUser": "CARCYAYU/APIUSER@carbon.super",
  "endUserTenantId": -1234,
  "applicationUUId": "5c2336af-fce6-49b2-8a96-a9f8bbf56924",
  "subscriber": "CARCYAYU/APIUSER",
  "subscriptionTier": "Unlimited",
  "applicationId": "3",
  "apiContext": "/bookings-read/carcyayu/v1",
  "apiName": "Bookings Read API",
  "jwtValidationInfo": {
    "user": "APIUSER",
    "issuer": "https:9443/oauth2/token",
    "expiryTime": 1664398068000,
    "issuedTime": 1664394468000,
    "consumerKey": "Zu5A7qXKXqfhu2eG9T4oYTlOgbEa",
    "valid": true,
    "scopes": [
      "default"
    ],
    "claims": {
      "sub": "APIUSER",
      "aut": "APPLICATION",
      "aud": [
        "Zu5A7qXKXqfhu2eG9T4oYTlOgbEa"
      ],
      "nbf": "Sep 28, 2022 10:47:48 PM",
      "azp": "Zu5A7qXKXqfhu2eG9T4oYTlOgbEa",
      "scope": "default",
      "iss": "https:9443/oauth2/token",
      "exp": "Sep 28, 2022 11:47:48 PM",
      "iat": "Sep 28, 2022 10:47:48 PM",
      "jti": "e794778b-5879-450c-a2cf-55789f5e9ae1"
    },
    "jti": "e794778b-5879-450c-a2cf-55789f5e9ae1",
    "validationCode": 0,
    "rawPayload": "eyJ4NXQiOiJOakE0TnpSaE16WXlaVGd6WXpZM1ltVXdOelkyWXprMFl6a3paVFk0Wm1RMFpXRmtZV0UwTlEiLCJraWQiOiJZV1prTWprd09EWXlPVEZrTTJNeU1qRXpOekptWlRkaVptWTNNR0kzTnpZM1l6RTRPV1ExTURFMVl6TTRNV1UyWTJKa1lUZGtORE15TjJVMk9HTmhNUV9SUzI1NiIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJBUElVU0VSIiwiYXV0IjoiQVBQTElDQVRJT04iLCJhdWQiOiJadTVBN3FYS1hxZmh1MmVHOVQ0b1lUbE9nYkVhIiwibmJmIjoxNjY0Mzk0NDY4LCJhenAiOiJadTVBN3FYS1hxZmh1MmVHOVQ0b1lUbE9nYkVhIiwic2NvcGUiOiJkZWZhdWx0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6OTQ0M1wvb2F1dGgyXC90b2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY2NDM5ODA2OCwiaWF0IjoxNjY0Mzk0NDY4LCJqdGkiOiJlNzk0Nzc4Yi01ODc5LTQ1MGMtYTJjZi01NTc4OWY1ZTlhZTEifQ.lRMyTWakh7YLHcGNlhQiKUklEo-do769KTaUt_gzVuotjyVbH7B5H1Kx2RY9Lp-UQkWnGSRxkwRHSH9c5VxwJoM8kmzZYULNbl-AvxDa7mXF6_UHHTTSwgg-ahtLBGe9d5bEOJ6mkEMzYdnOlQfmGSS6c97Wlg0Vyme61_9ZWhwspLJGmfBEtGSIRlqYPLOXlIJnMKEhWRO10TM9rtv70_yG5M4OwQu7OCILME1ubj4D6Vw1tQ7f_f10tBPTitRPPjbwQ-h-LMdZx6RFgfUmeKeirnHsa89xlkXt9JXl9BhMX-cutIqVlaUd6G-lsqNjyEd6oYiM_M0gw6YIjYlXfw",
    "keyManager": "Resident Key Manager",
    "isAppToken": true
  },
  "appAttributes": {},
  "sub": "APIUSER"
}
```

The object *"jwtValidationInfo"* has an array of *"claims"* where there is a field *"aut"* which has the value *"APPLICATION"*.
**Question.** **Is it equivalent to the *JWTGenerator* and the *context.getUserType()* method?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user type concept (‘application user’, ‘application’ ) is removed from latest versions of the api manager. You won’t find this in the UI as well. This functionality is now can be achieved using scopes. That is why it is not available in the jwt

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit please?  We want to know if it is an authenticated user (Ii.e. they logged in using username/password via the password flow when getting a token) or if they just got the token via client_credentials flow as an integration.  How do we see that from scopes?

Comment: You can create a custom grant handler extending the existing client credentials / password grant handler to include a predefined scope. This will include a scope to the token. Then define global scopes (without roles) using publisher portal and assign them to the resources. Access to the resource will be restricted based on the scope.